# How can I delete specific node from Firebase Databae?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete an element from my firebase database. I am using recycler view to list some elements and my intention is to swipe left one of the elements to delete it from both firebase database and the recycler view.
Here is my incomes recycler view

[recycler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68fgv.png)

And here is my database structure:
[image: database]

Let's say for example I want to remove the first one with the name "Gamer PC" how to I do that?

My code for now looks something like this

```
val itemTouchHelper = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
        when (direction) {
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT -> {
                val deleteItemReference = database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("Incomes").child("2022")
                
                // adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

            }
        }

    }


}
val itemHelper = ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelper)
itemHelper.attachToRecyclerView(seeAllIncomeRecyclerView)
```

For my recycler view I am using something called gropie

```
class IncomeItemForSeeAll(val incomeItemInSeeAll: IncomeSeeAll) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>(){
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {

        var valueAsString = incomeItemInSeeAll.itemValue
        var valueOfItemFormatted = formatNumberString(valueAsString)

        viewHolder.itemView.expenseCalendarTitle.text = incomeItemInSeeAll.itemName
        viewHolder.itemView.dateTV.text = incomeItemInSeeAll.itemDate
        viewHolder.itemView.expenseCalendarValue.text = valueOfItemFormatted+"$"
    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.expensecalendar
    }
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun formatNumberString(number: String): String? {
        val formatter = DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00")
        return formatter.format(java.lang.Double.parseDouble(number))
    }
}
```

And also my IncomeSeeAll class looks like this

```
@Parcelize
class IncomeSeeAll(val itemName: String, val itemDate: String, val itemValue: String) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("", "", "")

}
```

I know this is a long question I just wanted to make sure I described everything to make it easier to you.

Comment: Since you are suing Kotlin, I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to, just access that field/node by using DatabaseRefrence and set it's value to null using setValue(null); .